# TortiseSVN - commit Item failed error

Tags: tortoisesvn

I use tortise svn in VS2010.  When I go to commit my changes at the end of the day, I get the following error.

**Commit item '*folder* / *filename*' has copy flag but an invalid revision.**

What does that mean and how do I resolve it?  I Googled for it but really only saw a transcript of a rather esoteric discussion for a Java-related issue.

EDIT - 10/25/2010

Nothing?  Really?

Comment: Hmm. The only idea that comes to mind is the SVN equivalent to "Try restarting your machine": Try checking out a new working copy.

Comment: At the end of the day?  Commit early, commit often!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Pekka's comment.  Right click on the project folder -> TortoiseSVN -> Check for modifications.  Take note of the files you changed.

Create a new folder - and checkout the repository to the new folder.  Move the files that changed back into the new folder, replacing any existing ones.  Try your commit again.

You may try doing this with Windows Explorer instead of Visual Studio.

Comment: Why take notes of the files you changed? Just leave the dialog open, then later drag all the files from that dialog over to the new ones - the check-for-modifications dialog supports drag'n'drop!

Answer (score 1):

1. have you renamed that folder[say, folder1]?
2. If not then, "export" the content of that folder to somewhere else[say, folder2].
3. go back to parent of folder1 and delete then update folder1.
4. replace all the files[**not folder**s] in folder1 with the equivalent files from folder1
5. now commit folder1 independently after stealing any lock if exists.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try to get the latest revision (update before committing, but after you back up your code ;)?

It sounds like there is potentially something that is in conflict in a bad way - you may need to back up your files, update or check out a new working copy, and then replace checked out files with your old ones.

Answer (score 0):

check out a clean copy. put in the changes you previously made. commit.
do that, and try to forget your problems. it should work.